# Integrate actions sdk with aws lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, actions-on-google

I am trying to develop a google assistant app with actions sdk. I found lot of samples online which all are using google's firebase cloud functions to deploy. 
From this link(https://actions-on-google.github.io/actions-on-google-nodejs/) I also found that it is possible to deploy the actions sdk functions into aws lambda.
But unfortunately I did not find any sample which is showing how to write and deploy actions sdk into aws lambda.

Can anybody help me to write an application which is similar to the one shown here(https://github.com/actions-on-google/actionssdk-say-number-nodejs) and deploy it into aws lambda?

I tried the following to do the same. But it did not worked.

1. Created a folder and initialized it with "npm init".
2. Added index.js file.
3. Then ran the command "npm install actions-on-google". It appeared in the package.json file.
4. Created a zip folder of the entire source inside that folder I created.
5. Created a aws lambda function and uploaded the zip folder and set the "Handler" of the lambda function as "index.fulfillment".
6. Created an api gateway and linked it to the lambda function and deployed it.
7. Then took the url and editted the "actions.json" file and ran the gactions command.
8. Then when I started testing the app in the actions console using the simulator I am getting the error "UnparseableJsonResponse API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "error_message: Cannot find field"

Here is the code inside index.js file

```
'use strict';

const {actionssdk, SimpleResponse} = require('actions-on-google');

const app = actionssdk({debug: true});

app.intent('actions.intent.MAIN', (conv) => {
  conv.ask("welcome");
});


app.intent('actions.intent.TEXT', async (conv, input) => {
  conv.ask('You said ' + input);
});


exports.fulfillment = app
```

Here is the cloud watch logs from aws

```
2018-11-10T08:35:46.715Z    9dbb17f8-e4c3-11e8-bce3-730a5244a300
{
    "errorMessage": "Cannot convert undefined or null to object",
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "stackTrace": [
        "Function.keys (<anonymous>)",
        "Lambda.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/framework/lambda.js:36:36)",
        "Generator.next (<anonymous>)",
        "/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/framework/lambda.js:22:71",
        "new Promise (<anonymous>)",
        "__awaiter (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/framework/lambda.js:18:12)",
        "/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/framework/lambda.js:30:46",
        "omni (/var/task/node_modules/actions-on-google/dist/assistant.js:44:53)"
    ]
}
```

Comment: You mentioned you had problems with this code? Can you update the question to include the problems you're having, any error messages, logs, etc?

Comment: Thank you for the reply :) Unfortunately I do not have any logs. But I updated the question with all the steps I did.

Comment: There are no cloudwatch logs generated by the lambda? You have debug set to true, so there should be something. If you can also update the question to include the contents of the "debug" tab in the simulator, that can help.

Comment: Hi, I updated the question with logs from cloudwatch.

Comment: Hi, Now I was ale to fix the "--Bad handler app " issue. I changed the handler in lambda function to "index.fulfillment". Now I am getting another error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object". Anybody has any clue on this?

Comment: Can you clarify (by updating the question), in case others have the same problem, exactly *what* did you change to `index.fulfillment`

Comment: What version of node.js are you using in Lambda?

Comment: @Prisoner Done. I updated the question. The node version is node.js 8.10

Answer (score 1):

The code changes to host it on AWS are fairly straightforward. Instead of importing the firebase-functions library and using it, you just need to establish the lambda endpoint with the dialogflow app itself. So the code might look something like:

```
const { dialogflow } = require('actions-on-google')

const app = dialogflow()

// Setup intent handlers with app.intent() here

exports.factsAboutGoogle = app
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. How should I deploy it into aws. If it is a aws lambda function it is required to have a handler(for eg: index.handler) right?

Comment: Yes, `app` is that handler. The name you export is the public name of the handler you choose.

Comment: Thanks again for the reply. I created a aws lambda function and uploaded the code as a zip file and in the handler I given "app". Then when I started testing in actions console I am getting this error. Can you please help?  UnparseableJsonResponse
API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: "error_message: Cannot find field."

Comment: If you're still having problems, please update the original question with the code you're using, exactly where you're getting the error, and any other info you may have.